# Play Framework 2.x always send single response code

Tags: web, playframework, http-headers, playframework-2.0

Hopefully you guys can help me with this! I have a problem where I need to send a constant response code no matter what the request contains. If the request has bad JSON etc. The response I need to send is a 204 (No Content)

Here's my code where I try to send back a no content header.

```
    public Result response(){
    RequestBody body = request().body();
        System.out.println(body.asJson());
        return noContent();
    }
```

Now if I try and send a request containing JSON like below. It returns a 400 (Bad request). I want to send a 204 no matter what. Please let me know what you guys come up with.

```
JSON POST
{
   "mike":"mike
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

Sorry I replaced one of these lines of code and forgot to update this. Above I only return 204's, but if my client sends me bad JSON then I still return a 400.

Comment: If it isn't going to be JSON, don't call `asJson`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve, but you can always return a 204 HTTP response code with `return status(204)`.

Comment: @Ryan the request coming in are almost always JSON, but sometimes the client will send me something else. In my case I still need to return a 204.

Comment: @Kris even if I have a straight `public Result answer(){ return status(204)} ` and I send in some bad JSON, I get a 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the global settings for play. 
Create a class that extends Global Settings and override whichever method you want.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
@Override
    public Promise<Result> onBadRequest(RequestHeader arg0, String arg1) {
         super.onBadRequest(arg0, arg1);
        return F.Promise.promise(()->{return play.mvc.Results.noContent();});
    }
}
```

For more information : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaGlobal

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result response() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    if(json == null){
        return noContent();
    }else{
        // Get json content from request and process rest..
    }
    return ok("");
}
```

By using above approach, a 204 HTTP response will be automatically returned for non JSON requests.

Comment: Returns a 400 bad request :(

Answer (score 0):

To return 204, you can use **noContent** method

For that replace `ok()` by `noContent()`